# R variable parts of a filename

Tags: r

This is a simple rquest, but I can't find anything on the topic. I have a file, lets call it:

```
infile <- file("clim.bin.1201","rb")
```

12 is the month and 01 is the day of the month. How can I name the 'infile' so that I don't have to change the 'infile <- file("clim.bin.1201","rb") line, but just change the number of the month and day, which will be defined at the top of the script?

Comment: There is a difference between `"clim.bin.1201"` and `clim.bin.1201` - the first is a literal character string, the second is the name of an R object that might have a character value. What have you got?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As well as JLLagrange's `sprintf` solution, you can use `paste0`:

```
filename <- paste0("clim.bin.", mon, day)
infile <- file(filename, "rb")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
filename <- sprintf("clim.bin.%02d%02d",mon,day)
infile <- file(filename,"rb")
```

This assumes month and day are numeric.